# Give the target attribute to a variable, just in case we need to point at them, in Fortran

Tags: pointers, fortran

I have a code that makes extensive use of a type, let say, for simplicity:

```
type, public :: my_type
    real, allocatable, dimension(:)     :: x
    real, allocatable, dimension(:,:)   :: coeffs
end type my_type
...
type(my_type) :: data
```

Later in the code, we need to write `data%x` and `data%coeffs` to a file.
Whether the user wants it or not, this file could be written in a standard unformatted binary file and recently we add the possibility to write the file in HDF5 format.

In this case, when creating the data sets for `data%x` or `data%coeffs`, I need to pass a pointer, pointing on them, as argument to some hdf5 subroutines. This pointer can be defined as follow:

```
f_ptr = c_loc( data%x(1) )
```

But to do that, I should have given the target attribute to `x` and `coeffs` in `my_type` definition.

My questions are then:

- is it safe to give this target attribute, just in case, even if, in the end, the user does not want to use HDF5 format ?
- Would it have an impact on performance ?
- Would it be better to make, in the routine that writes the data, a local copy of `data%x` and `data%coeffs` to same shape arrays with the target attribute and then point at them and pass the pointer to hdf5 subroutines ?

If it helps, this code can be compiled either with `gfortran` or `ifort`.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is safe; maybe; there's no need to make a copy.

Typically you would pass `data%x` (and then `data%coeffs`) to a procedure that does the HDF5 dataset writing as a actual argument, say associated with a dummy array `arg`.  If so, just give `arg` the TARGET attribute.

```
call write_array_to_hdf5_file(data%x, ...)

subroutine write_array_to_hdf5_file(arg, ...)
  real, intent(in), target :: arg(:)
  ...
  call h5d_write_f(..., c_loc(arg))
```

If the actual argument does not have the target attribute, then pointers associated with `arg` become undefined when the `write_array_to_hdf5_file` procedure finishes execution.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have misunderstood how `target` works in Fortran. If I have not misunderstood you, you want to make `data%x` and `data%coeffs` targets, by giving the `x` and `coeffs` member variables the `target` attribute, as

```
type, public :: my_type
    real, allocatable, dimension(:), target   :: x
    real, allocatable, dimension(:,:), target :: coeffs
end type my_type
type(my_type) :: data
```

but this is not valid syntax. To quote [Intel](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/fortran-compiler-oneapi-dev-guide-and-reference/top/language-reference/a-to-z-reference/t-to-z/target-statement.html):

> The TARGET attribute can be specified in a type declaration statement or a TARGET statement

This means the `target` attribute can only be applied to instances of variables, not to their definitions.

And so to make `data%x` and `data%coeffs` targets, you should instead give `data` the `target` attribute, as

```
type, public :: my_type
    real, allocatable, dimension(:)   :: x
    real, allocatable, dimension(:,:) :: coeffs
end type my_type
type(my_type), target :: data
```

This hopefully also answers your question on usage; you only need to give the `target` attribute to those instances of `my_type` which need it.